# grid.appScope not working for ui grid angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Wanted to access a function from my custom cellTemplate. For that, i am using grid.appScope. Following is the code :

```
$scope.test = function(){
    alert('a');
  };

columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name',      displayName: 'Name', cellTemplate: '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.test()">ABCDEFGH</div>' },
      { field: 'id',      displayName: 'ID' }
]
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue with the above code ?

Comment: Where are you calling this function and it is still unclear.

Comment: Entire code is written in a controller. Function "test()" is called from the cellTemplate.

Answer (score 4):

I have face the same problem and able to resolve it in my case we have made the grid as directive in that it is not able to recognize the test function. In order to do that just use $parent scope

like this

```
grid.appScope.$parent.test();
```

Comment: this answer has helped me understand how the scope works. I was trying to access a function in grid.appScope.$ctrl.function(). I recommend the browser extension AngularJS Batarang so you can visualize the model tree.